# Why adding custom collection operation removes post method?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com, symfony5

If I use only the `@ApiResource()` annotation result is as follows:

[image: open-api docs screen-shot]

When I try to add a custom operation, the `post` collection operation is missing:

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get", "find_between" = {
 *          "method"="GET",
 *          "path"="/bookings/find_between",
 *          "openapi_context" = {
 *                  "parameters" = {
 *                      {
 *                          "name" = "startAt",
 *                          "in" = "query",
 *                          "description" = "Start date & time for bookings retrieval",
 *                          "required" = "true",
 *                          "type" : "string",
 *                          "format" : "date-time"
 *                      },
 *                      {
 *                          "name" = "endAt",
 *                          "in" = "query",
 *                          "description" = "End date & time for bookings retrieval",
 *                          "required" = "true",
 *                          "type" : "string",
 *                          "format" : "date-time"
 *                      }
 *                  }
 *               }
 *          }
 *     },
 * )
```

[image: open-api documentations screenshot with missing post operation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, as explained in the [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations):

> If no operation is specified, all default CRUD operations are automatically registered. It is also possible - and recommended for large projects - to define operations explicitly.

If you define the operations explicitly, only the defined operations will be available.

The default **item** operations are:

- get
- put
- delete

The default **collection** operations are:

- get
- post

In your example you are defining two collection operations: `get` and `find_between`. Since `post` is also a collection operation, by omitting it you have effectively **disabled** that operation.

If you are going to define explicitly any one operation in a group (item, collection); you need to define all the ones you want to enable.

Comment: When I tried example:  itemOperations={"post"} I've error no route post. Have no idea how to restore post.

Comment: `post` is a collection operation, not an item operation. That's the reason you have disabled it. You explicitly define the `get` collection operation and a custom collection operation, but do not enable the `post` collection operation.